# Why is my Perl script printing incorrect values when not using hard-coded values?

Tags: perl

I use an A/D converter to get some results of an electric conductivity probe. I use a miniEC interface from [Sparky's Widgets](https://www.sparkyswidgets.com/). We run a calibration and get the slope and the intercept values. When I am testing this values with this calibration in a static script the result is correct.

See here, not a big thing but a proof that my calibration works well. The result is correct.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $slope     = "0.048684077307972626";
my $intercept = "24.831896523430906";

$ECdec = 62.5;

print "$ECdec \n";

###lin
$EC1 = ( ( $ECdec - $intercept ) / $slope );

print "Electric Conductivity $EC1 µS/m \n";
```

Output is:

```
62.5
Electric Conductivity 773.725323749752 �S/m
```

When I swap the static value `$ECdec` to the output of the A/D Converter and try to get a result it is totally wrong. Can anyone see my failure?

Here is the Perl which reads the probes value from the converter, swap the bytes, convert it to decimal and then add the linear regression. What did I do wrong?

```perl
    #!/usr/bin/perl

my $dir = '/var/www/motion';

my $slope = "0.048684077307972626";
my $intercept = "24.831896523430906";

###get value 
my $EC = `sudo i2cget -y 1 0x4a 0x00 w` ;

print "$EC \n";

###swap 
my $ECswap = $EC;
substr $ECswap, 4, 0, substr $ECswap, 2, 2, q();

print "$ECswap \n";

###convert to decimal
$ECdec = hex($ECswap);

print "$ECdec \n";

$ECvalue = ($ECdec - $ECintercept)/$slope);

print "$ECvalue"
#$rrd = `/usr/bin/rrdtool update $dir/homeec.rrd N:$ECdec`;

####system ("clear");
print "Electric Conductivity $ECdec µS/m \n";
```

Output here is:

```
0x5303 
0x0353
851 
Electric Conductivity 16969.9858590372 �S/m
```

Comment: Those `print`s, what do they show?  Please show the output. You have `62.5` hard-coded, what are the numbers in the second case?

Comment: sorry forget the output

output from 1st script:
62.5
Electric Conductivity 773.725323749752 �S/m 

output from the 2nd:
0x5303 
0x0353
851 
Electric Conductivity 16969.9858590372 �S/m

i use the print command to see what happen on every step to see my error.

Comment: edited the 1st post

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. I take it that you know that you need to do that swap, etc.  The hex for `62.3` is `0x3E`, far off from what you work with.  Is something wrong with the input?

Comment: it is an 12bit AD Converter so i get always a value like 0x5303, must swap this bytes from 0x5303 to 0x0353 and convert it to decimal. Then calculate the linear regression. The output fromt he AD Converter as an example at a referenced EC value 1974 microSiemens/cm: Here i took the values from the AD Converter and put every gathered value i an colum file:

0x8600
0x6d00
0x8a00
0x6e00
0x7800
0x7000
0x7d00
0x8000
0x8700
0x7700
0x7400
0x7300
0x7600
0x9000
0x7a00
0x6a00
0x7b00
0x7400
0x7500
0x7900
0x8200
0x6e00
0x7b00
0x7c00

and so on....

Comment: There is no linear regression anywhere in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing `$ECdec` in your output instead of `$ECvalue`

Also, please always post your real code. The program you have shown won't compile and is clearly not the one that is giving you problems

This is how your program should look

You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of even the most trivial Perl programs, and declare all of your variables with `my`

You should always `use utf8` if your code contains non-ASCII characters like the Greek mu `µ` in microSiemens. Perl doesn't support source code encoded other than in 7-bit ASCII or UTF-8. I don't know whether your terminal expects UTF-8 characters, and you may need to alter the `use open` statement

I have commented out your call to i2cget to retrieve a real value and subsituted a constant string instead

I have also converted the hex string to binary before swapping the bytes for speed, but it's far from critical and you should retain the character swap if you find it more readable. I would use a regular expression and write it like this

```perl
die unless $EChex =~ /0x(\p{hex}{2})(\p{hex}{2})/;
my $EC = hex($2.$1);
```

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use open qw/ :std :encoding(utf8) /;

use constant DIR       => '/var/www/motion';
use constant SLOPE     => 0.048684077307972626;
use constant INTERCEPT => 24.831896523430906;

# my $EChex = `sudo i2cget -y 1 0x4a 0x00 w` ;
my $EChex = '0x5303';
printf "\$EChex = %s\n", $EChex;

my $EC = hex $EChex;
printf "\$EC = %s\n", $EC;

$EC = (($EC & 0xFF00) >> 8) | (($EC & 0xFF) << 8); # swap bytes

my $ECvalue = ($EC - INTERCEPT) / SLOPE;

printf "Electric Conductivity %.3fµS/m \n", $ECvalue;
```

#### output

```
$EChex = 0x5303
$EC = 21251
Electric Conductivity 16969.986µS/m
```

Comment: Yes, thats wrong....  i can only access this debian in the evening. i can not check this now. I will correct this... thanks!

Comment: That made my day! I get an exact result and a lesson that i should learn the perl basics. I owe you an favor, Borodin!